# Responsive div at the center. Px div in each side

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have different rows. Each one has a div on the left and one on the right. They must have 50px. At the center I need a div that must be responsive, it should adapt to the width of the window. I solved with flex but I am worried about older browsers. Is there another way to do that effect?

That structure is essential to understand my project and I cannot have a fall back for people with older browsers. Those people will see nothing.

This are the conditions:
- div left and div right should have 50px
- div center should be responsive, fill the remain space with a margin of 10px on left and right

This is what I have tried and more or less works but only in new browsers:

```css
#wrap {
 position: relative;
 margin: 20px auto;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: red;
}
 
.row {
 position: relative;
 height: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 
 display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 background-color: lightgray;
}
 
.left {
 width: 50px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin-right: 10px;
 background-color: grey;
}
 
.center {
 min-height: 30px; line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: blue;
 flex-grow: 1;
}
 
.right {
 width: 50px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 10px;
 background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="center">center</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="center">center</div>
  <div class="right">right</div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can use `width: calc(100% - 120px);`**

That means that the `.center` class will take the 100% with of the parent element, less 120px (50 for .right and .left elements and 10 for its margins).

For some reason in this snippet I had to set `width: calc(100% - 128px);`

```css
#wrap {
 margin: 20px auto;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: red;
}

.row {
 height: 30px; margin-bottom: 10px; background-color: green;
}

.left,
.right {
 width: 50px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: grey;
}

.left { margin-right: 10px; }
.right { margin-left: 10px; }

.center {
 min-height: 30px; line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 128px);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="center">center</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="center">center</div>
  <div class="right">right</div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Be aware that in your answer you forgot the # in wrap. Also you give it 400px and to be responsive it makes more sense to give % like 80%

Comment: It is simpler than flex and if has a bit better browser support. So, it is an improvement. But still I am afraid of old browsers as I cannot have a fall back for them. That structure is essential to understand my project

Comment: Note that I change more things than just `width: calc`. For example, .center has `display: inline-block`. And rewrite .left and .right.

Comment: If I can think of another option, I'll add it. Hope it help.

Comment: It really helps. Thank you

Comment: I tried to add min-width: 500px; to #wrap and it makes nothing. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

What are your exact browser support requirements? Flexbox is indeed the right tool for this job, and with a CSS pre- or post-processor (say, Autoprefixer) you can get support for every modern browser including the ones that need vendor-specific syntax for Flexbox (https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

If you require support for, say IE9, then you can use CSS @supports at-rules (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) to target browsers that can't do Flexbox.

Comment: I do not have specific browser support requirements. That structure is essential to understand my project and I cannot have a fall back for people with older browsers. Those people will see nothing.

Comment: Not sure I understand your response. You can use the @supports rule to craft a fallback approach so that older browsers see the intended layout, they'd just achieve it using display:table or another older but still-workable approach.