# reallocate items inside a div with responsive pages

Tags: html, css, responsive

I edited literally a few lines from the code taken from this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56564232/responsive-div-at-the-center-px-div-in-each-side/56564903)

```css
#wrap {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 80%;
    
}

.separator { 
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.row {
    height: 30px; margin-bottom: 10px; background-color: green;
}

.left,
.right {
    width: 33%; height: 30px; line-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: grey;
}

.left { margin-right: 10px; }
.right { margin-left: 10px; }

.center {
    min-height: 30px; line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="center">center</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="center">center</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>  

</div>
```

when the sizes of the windows becomes too small, for example on mobile, it will become a mess. When this happens, how can I reallocate items vertically, one items for line, where the left will be the first, the center the second, and so.

I'm actually using this in React, just to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With display `grid`

You can use **`grid-template-areas`** on the ***grid parent*** **selectors** and **`grid-areas`** on the ***grid children*** **selectors** to place the elements in the *order* you want them to be displayed in the document despite their order in the HTML. You just change the grid properties in your media query.

```css
#cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "left-1 center-1 right-1" 
    "left-2 center-2 right-2";
  gap: .5rem;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}


.left-1 {
  grid-area: left-1;
}

.left-2 {
  grid-area: left-2;
}

.center-1 {
  grid-area: center-1;
}

.center-2 {
  grid-area: center-2;
}

.right-1 {
  grid-area: right-1;
}

.right-2 {
  grid-area: right-2;
}


/* mobile */

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #cont {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-columns: auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "left-1" 
        "left-2" 
        "center-1" 
        "center-2" 
        "right-1" 
        "right-2";
    gap: .5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div class="left-1 box">left</div>
  <div class="center-1 box">center</div>
  <div class="right-1 box">right</div>
  <div class="left-2 box">left</div>
  <div class="center-2 box">center</div>
  <div class="right-2 box">right</div>
</div>
```

### You could do the following without using display grid and just adding a media query:

You however do not have control of re-ordering the elements like you do with grid or flex display, you could use [**`box-ordinal-group`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-ordinal-group) to change the order of the elements, *however* it has been taken out of the ***standard*** with the introduction of ***flex*** - ***order*** and ***grid***.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cont {
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px;
}

.box {
  min-width: calc(33.3% - 5px);
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box~.box {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #cont {
    width: calc(100% - 5px);
    margin: 5px;
  }
  .box {
    min-width: calc(100% - 5px);
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div class="box">left</div>
  <div class="box">center</div>
  <div class="box">right</div>
  <div class="box">left</div>
  <div class="box">center</div>
  <div class="box">right</div>
</div>
```

### Using ***flex box*** with ***[order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)***

*~ Change the visual **order** of your content when using Flexbox.*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  min-width: calc(33.3% - 10px);
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #cont {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    margin: 5px;
  }
  .box {
    min-width: calc(100% - 10px);
    height: 100px;
  }
  .box:nth-of-type(1) {
    order: 1;
  }
  .box:nth-of-type(2) {
    order: 3;
  }
  .box:nth-of-type(3) {
    order: 5;
  }
  .box:nth-of-type(4) {
    order: 2;
  }
  .box:nth-of-type(5) {
    order: 4;
  }
  .box:nth-of-type(6) {
    order: 6;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div class="box">left row 1</div>
  <div class="box">center row 1</div>
  <div class="box">right row 1</div>
  <div class="box">left row 2</div>
  <div class="box">center row 2</div>
  <div class="box">right row 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS Flexbox to position the items side-by-side on large screens, and use a media query to detect mobile devices and align the items vertically.

```css
#wrap {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 80%;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
/* mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">left</div>
    <div class="box">center</div>
    <div class="box">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">left</div>
    <div class="box">center</div>
    <div class="box">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this works fine but it would be better if in the vertical case it would be 
left, left, center, center, right, right

Comment: aah, okay. In that case I would use dale's answer (below mine).